# Login window for WPF application (VS 2013)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, authentication, navigation

I am working on WPF application for Windows 7 using MVVM pattern. As a part of it I need to provide authorization functionality through Windows AD.

So, firstly once application is launched, Login screen needs to be shown and once authorization is successful - Main application screen.

On this stage I have doubts regarding application design, i.e to use two separate windows (hide first/ display next) or maybe one master window with frame and pages. I need to comply with MVVM ideas as well.

Currently I have implemented it using 2 separate windows (Main window will comprise frame for navigation purposes) in following way:

**Login Window XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.LoginWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WPF.ViewModels"
        Title="LoginWindow" Height="300" Width="300" WindowStyle="ToolWindow">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:LoginViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="177*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="115*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="47,71,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{ Binding Login, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="201" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,175,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Login, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22" Width="201" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32" Width="201" PasswordChanged="PasswordBox_PasswordChanged" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="108,143,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="84" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Nothing special here, window is linked to `LoginViewModel` view model, which has properties for login/password and command to start credential validation.

**Login View Model**

```
namespace WPF.ViewModels
{
    public class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

         public event EventHandler LoginCompleted;

         public void RaiseLoginCompleted()
        {
            if (LoginCompleted != null)
            {
                LoginCompleted(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        private string login;
        private string password;

        public string Login
        {
            get { return login; }
            set { login = value; OnPropertyChanged("Login"); }
        }

        public string Password {
            private get { return password; }
            set { password = value; OnPropertyChanged("Password"); }
        }

        public void LoginOp(object o)
        {
            #Validation logic
            RaiseLoginCompleted();
        }

        public ICommand LoginCommand { get; set; }

        public LoginViewModel() {    
            LoginCommand = new DelegateCommand(LoginOp);
            OnPropertyChanged("LoginOp");
        }   
    }
}
```

Here `LoginCompleted` event is present, which is being fired by `RaiseLoginCompleted()` once authorization validation is successfully completed.

The main windows switching logic is present within overridden OnStartup method in App class:

**App Class**

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            Window LoginWindow = new LoginWindow();
            LoginWindow.Show();
            ((LoginViewModel)LoginWindow.DataContext).LoginCompleted += (s, ev) =>
            {
                Window MainWindow = new MainWindow();
                LoginWindow.Hide();
                LoginWindow.Close();
                MainWindow.Show();
            };   
        }
    }
```

`LoginCompleted` event is being listened and once it's detected Login Window is being closed and Main Window is shown afterwards.

I find this solution not ideal from MVVM perspective, also I have two windows.

Could you please comment/advise on better solution for this task? Is it possible to implement it with Pages approach given that I am going to have menu, pages and frame in my main window (2 frames?!).

Comment: if you want to login with AD, why do you need a login view??? Single-Sign-On?!?!?!

Comment: SSO won't work in that case as user has 2 accounts, one which is used to login to the PC and another one to connect to other applications (so AD validation needs to be done against this second account).

Comment: :-O this sounds weird. But your I.T. department would have their reasons... if I would be an employee and having mutliple windows accounts I would quite immediately.